# i run ory kratos on docker. how can i create identities with password using username & password schema for testing purpose

Tags: go, ory, kratos

i run ory kratos on docker. i create identities as admin without password using the email and name fields. i need to create them with password using the username and password schema and then test the login

```
createIdentityBody := *ory.NewCreateIdentityBody(
        "default",


        map[string]interface{}{
            "email": "mmm123",
            "name": map[string]string{
            "first": "user6",
            "last":  "user66",
             },
        },
    )
    createdIdentity, r, err := apiClient.IdentityApi.CreateIdentity(context.Background()).CreateIdentityBody(createIdentityBody).Execute()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error when calling `FrontendApi.CreateIdentity``: %v\n", err)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Full HTTP response: %v\n", r)
    }
```